Is it possible to use nginx reverse proxy between user (site visitor) and cloudflare cdn?
I have some websites, and i use cloudflare cdn with proxy setting enabled. So now the chain is:
website visitor -> cloudflare -> my webserver
I want to add some tricky thing - to add one more vps server in the chain, that will proxy requests only on 80 and 443 ports from website visitor to cloudflare, and do some another things for some other ports (have it's own mail server / surveillance server, etc). So what i want to have finally:
website visitor -> vps with nginx as reverse proxy -> cloudflare -> my webserver
So, for 80/443 port requests vps with nginx proxy to cloudflare, for other ports - do not proxy but works on its own.
I know how to use nginx reverse proxy to proxy requests on some ports to other external ip address, editing config file like etc/nginx/conf.d/1.2.3.4.conf, where 1.2.3.4 is the ip of nginx server, like this:
server {
listen 80;
server_name 1.2.3.4;
location / {
proxy_pass http://5.6.7.8; # external address of real web server
proxy_cache off;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_redirect off;
charset off;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}

but instead of proxy_pass to http://5.6.7.8 i need to proxy to cloudflare cdn, where, of course, only ns-servers are known, but no external ip address. Also i cannot remove cloudflare cdn from the chain.
What can be a solution in my case?
I googled some information about it, also nginx documentaion, but with no success.

Why would you bother using a CDN when you bottleneck access with a simple proxy???

CDN improves speed of my site. It holds a LOT OF cache (i have "cache everything" rule enabled), also other things that improves speed of my website.

... and the proxy then ruins the caching.

It doesn't necessarily "ruin the caching" but even if it's done right, this makes the CDN worse than redundant. The resulting architecture will be slower than just bypassing Cloudflare.

Guys, you are right about slowing, but i need this chain with cloudflare. Is there a way to run something like dns redirection? I meen the domain will have dns like ns1.myowndnsserver.com and ns2.myowndnsserver.com, and it will proxy requests to cloudflare's dns?
